# jquery animate browser window

Tags: jquery, browser, window, jquery-animate

Is there a way to animate a browser window using jquery. Right now I'm essentially using this:

```
 $(window).animate({
    left: '+=50'
  }, 5000});
```

The reason why it isn't working is probably obvious, although not for me. I eventually need to loop an animate effect so that the browser will move back and forth dynamically.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope your site is **really** entertaining and worthwhile.

Comment: haha, i hope so. it's experimental, not an ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`window.moveBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.moveBy). Don't be surprised when many browsers refuse to obey, as moving the window is highly obnoxious and of little (if any) worth.